# Ebean PersistenceException- don't see datasource

Tags: java, scala, orm, playframework, ebean

I'am new in play framework world. Recently, I try launch simple application which use `Ebean` ORM.

Database part of my `application.conf` file look like:

```
 datasource.default.username= user
 datasource.default.password= ""
 datasource.default.databaseUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
 datasource.default.databaseDriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

 ebean.default="models.*"
```

When I try do some operation using Ebean- for example

```
Ebean.beginTransaction();
```

It cause:

```
    play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[PersistenceException: The default EbeanServer has not been defined? This is normally set via the ebean.datasource.default property. Otherwise it should be registered programatically via registerServer()]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: The default EbeanServer has not been defined? This is normally set via the ebean.datasource.default property. Otherwise it should be registered programatically via registerServer()
    at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean$ServerManager.getPrimaryServer(Ebean.java:197) ~[ebean-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean$ServerManager.access$300(Ebean.java:147) ~[ebean-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.beginTransaction(Ebean.java:374) ~[ebean-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at controllers.Application2.doSthInJava(Application2.java:32) ~[na:na]
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(routes_routing.scala:57) ~[na:na]
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(routes_routing.scala:57) ~[na:na]
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In Play 2.x the correct syntax is:

```
db.default.user="your user"
db.default.password="your pass"
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
db.default.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

ebean.default="models.*"
```

Comment: After change It stil cause this same `PersistenceException`.

Comment: Try to add `dbplugin=enabled` and run `activator clean ~run`